# Math.Round() - LINQ Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, math

I am running a LINQ query that is using local "let" variables to calculate a local value to compare against a parameter that is passed into the query.

I have the following query:

```
Items = from lead in Items
        let total = lead.NurtureActions.Count(q => !q.Deleted)
        let completed = lead.NurtureActions.Count(nurtureAction => nurtureAction.Completed && !nurtureAction.Deleted)
        let percentage = Math.Round((Double)((completed/total)*100),0,MidpointRounding.ToEven)
        where 
            total>0 && 
            percentage == progress
        select lead;
```

The part that is really important above is the following line:

```
let percentage = Math.Round((Double)((completed/total)*100),0,MidpointRounding.ToEven)
```

As you can see in my query, I am comparing the result of that query with `progress`, which is passed into my function.

For example: I might pass in the value `8`, so `progress` will have the value `8`. But the calculated `percentage` might initially be `8.223`, but I need that to round to `8`.

I believed that I was doing this correctly, but for some reason, something is not working correctly.

Any ideas of what might be throwing the rounding off? I have also tried the `AwayFromZero` option for rounding, but that doesn't work either.

**Edit** For those who requested more information, I am not sure what value it is calculating. I am not experienced with debugging LINQ queries, and wouldn't know where to begin to find out what that value is. I would provide it if I knew how to get it.

Comment: What happens? What values do you see in the debugger?

Comment: "...something is not working correctly." What's not working correctly? What are you seeing? Is it rounding up when it should round down?

Comment: You've said twice now that something "doesn't work" - but not said what's actually happening.

Comment: antisanity - I want it to round correctly based on MidpointRound setting. If it is above midpoint, then round up, else round down.

Comment: That's what you _want_. What do you ***get***?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Random guess: `total` and `completed` are `int`s, so `(completed/total)` results in a truncated value. The truncated value is multiplied by 100 and *then* converted to `double`.

I guess this  produces unexpected results in some cases if you expect that `(completed/total)` returns a `double`.

*Fix:*

```
let total = (double)lead.NurtureActions.Count(...)
let completed = (double)lead.NurtureActions.Count(...)
let percentage = Math.Round((completed/total)*100, ...)
```